# C# Datetime Conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005, .net-2.0

I am developing WinForm application on .NET 2.0 and SQL Server Express 2005.

I am facing a problem with datetime conversion.

1)  I need to display datetime(datetimepicker) on UI like "dd/MM/yyyy" so I am using

```
public static void ChangeDateFormat(DateTimePicker dtp)
{
    dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dtp.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

2) For inserting data to SQL Server I am using

```
datetimePicker1.ToShortDateString()
```

3) Getting data from SQL Server

```
Convert(varchar(10),dt,103)
```

4)  Assign string date "31/03/2013" to datetimepiker

```
public static DateTime StringToDate(string value)
{
    IFormatProvider formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value, formatProvider);
    return dt;
}
```

5)  Assign SQL date to datetimepicker

```
Select dt from ams

datetimepicker1.value=DateTimeClass.dbDateTime( dt );

public static DateTime dbDateTime(string value)
{
    IFormatProvider formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value, formatProvider);
    return dt;
}
```

Problem : if a user changed region or date format of Windows, an error occurs.

I am pretty confused. I need to make my application region independent.

Comment: This all can be solved if you just return `Date` from Sql Server, instead of converting it to a string at SQL Server end. Then you will not need parsing. You can do the formatting at C# like `var formattedString = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: You need to explain *clearly* (and in your question, not via a comment) what "error occurs" means.

Comment: You also ought to be passing it to SQL as a `Date` instead of a string as well. Formatting issues only (tend to) arise when you (inappropriately) force datetime data to be represented as strings instead.

Comment: @Habib i think this is good point, do you think is this aware of region ? but some place i really need to convert '31/03/2014' to datetime.

Comment: @SudhakarChaudhary, for converting to string with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would ignore the current region and just consider the format provided. Same is true for ParseExact.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you want to convert a string from sql into a DataTime value, but that you save the DateTime as a string in sql server. By saving your value as a Date, you do not have to convert and have no problems with regions, etc. The solution should be changing your sql column to a date type instead of trying to convert dates from which you have to guess the formatting.